# How to create XML with declared namespace?

Tags: java, xml, namespaces

I am creating a xml request using java. 
I am new in creating xmls using java.

Here is code:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("UserRequest");
            rootElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:ns0", "https://com.user.req");
            rootElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            // user element
            Element user = doc.createElement("User");
            rootElement.appendChild(user);

            // userAttributes element
            Element userAttr = doc.createElement("UserAttributes");
            rootElement.appendChild(userAttr);


            // name elements
            Element name = doc.createElement("Name");
            name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("hello"));
            userAttr.appendChild(name);
            // value elements
            Element value = doc.createElement("Value");
            name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("dude"));
            userAttr.appendChild(value);
```

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UserRequest 
xmlns:ns0="https://com.user.req" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:type="ns0:UserRequest">
  <User/>
  <UserAttributes>
    <Name>hello</Name>
    <Value>dude</Value>
  </UserAttributes>
</UserRequest>
```

**Generated output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UserRequest 
xmlns:ns0="https://com.user.req" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

  <User/>
  <UserAttributes>
    <Name>hello</Name>
    <Value>dude</Value>
  </UserAttributes>
</UserRequest>
```

***How to get correct namespace (as shown at expected section).***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the namespaces in your generated output. However this is an accident ... you're using [`setAttributeNS()`](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setAttributeNS_java.lang.String__java.lang.String__java.lang.String_) to do something it's not intended for.

Read up on XML namespace declarations and namespace prefixes. That will be a lot easier than trying to explain point-by-point why you're not getting what you expected. For example, `xmlns` is not a namespace prefix, and `xsi:type` is not a namespace.

Instead of trying to create the desired namespace declarations as if they were normal attributes, delete these two lines

```
rootElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/",
        "xmlns:ns0", "https://com.user.req");
rootElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/",
        "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

and instead use

```
rootElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        "xsi:type", "ns0:UserRequest");
```

This should give you most of your expected output, except for the `ns0` namespace prefix declaration. It won't generate that because you're not using `ns0` on any element or attribute. Did you mean to have

```
<ns0:UserRequest ...
```

in your expected output?