# DomException when creating a xml-file with namespaces via jdom

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I want to create a xml-file that should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" version="1.1" creator="Wikipedia"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
```

When creating this with setAttributeNS and executing I get a DomException that says I wanted to create a file that is wrong regarding the namespaces.

Here is the code:

```
try{
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        DOMImplementation di = db.getDOMImplementation();
        Document doc = di.createDocument("http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1", "gpx", null);
        doc.setXmlVersion("1.0");
        Element rootgpx = doc.getDocumentElement();
        rootgpx.setAttributeNS("http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1", "xmlns", "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1");
        rootgpx.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" );
        rootgpx.setAttributeNS("http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd", "xsi:schemaLocation", "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd");
        doc.appendChild(rootgpx);
```

I am obviously doing something wrong, but i dont know what.
Could somebody please help?

Comment: Are you using DOM or JDOM? I'm confused.

Comment: I am using JDom

Comment: But JDOM's `Element` class doesn't have a `setAttributeNS()` method, and its `Document` class doesn't have a `getDocumentElement()` method.

Comment: Now I am confused - Eclipse offers setAttributeNS() and i read through some questions here on the forum and they said its done like this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862775/how-to-create-xml-with-declared-namespace. Well this might explain the Exception.

Comment: Check the imports at the top of the Java module to see what package the classes Document and Element are in.

Comment: its org.w3c.dom...

Comment: The post you cited is using DOM, though it doesn't say so. I'm afraid 90% of people looking for an XML tree model in Java use DOM, despite the fact that it's the worst choice possible: JDOM2 and XOM are far better designed.